# Link embedded in my div is not clickable

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my website I can't get the TripAdvisor widget on the footer to link to a page. It won't register if you click it.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Here's the html and css of the widget:

```
<div class="tripAdvisorFooter">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g3801136-d11918090-Reviews-Timber_Trail_Lodge-Pureora_Forest_Park_Manawatu_Wanganui_Region_North_Island.html">
    <picture>
      <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/img/cdsi/img2/badges/ollie-11424-2.gif">
      <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png">
    </picture>
  </a>
</div>

   .tripAdvisorFooter {
        position: absolute;
        left: 180px;
      }
   .tripAdvisorFooter a {
        z-index: 1;
    }
   @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {      
    .tripAdvisorFooter { 
      top: 80px;
      left: 30px;
    }
  }
```

If you have a look at the other widgets you can see that they use almost the exact same code yet are clickable.

Also if it's useful to note, I'm using Wordpress. Let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks Meagar for the edits.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix, add a z-index to the class tripAdvisorFooter. Something like

```
.tripAdvisorFooter {
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Because this class is set to position absolute, the links to the right of it span above and all the way to the left, and since it sits above, you can't click on the tripadvisor link.